# Is there a way to convert Keystore of instance PKCS11 to JKS programmatically?

Tags: java, pkcs#11, jks

I am using a smart card and the keystore instance is in PKCS11 format.
I wanted to create a .jks file with the Certificate from the smart card.
Is there a way to achieve it programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: If you only want the certificate, it's a public document: there's nothing stopping you from doing that. If you literally want to do what your title says, you don't want to do it at all. The private key is embedded in the smart card for good security reasons: what you are requesting is a *prima facie* security breach.

Answer (score 0):

You can, (**HOWEVER, IT IS NOT ADVISABLE**), provided if the hardware token manufacturer supports it and if you have created your PKCS#11 Objects as extractable.

**WARNING**: *What you are trying to do is **NOT** secure. You are taking away the purpose of what the hardware tokens are meant to do. Once a secret Object is created in a hardware token, it doesn't see the light of the day.*

For a PKCS11 Object to be extractable, you have to set the `CKA_EXTRACTABLE` to `true`, `CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE` to `false`, `CKA_SENSITIVE` to `false` and `CKA_ALWAYS_SENSITIVE` to `false`.

Most hardware token manufacturer's don't support this. Assuming that you have found a vendor who supports this, and you have created the PKCS11 Objects with the above attributes, you can do it as below.

You can loop through your PKCS11 KeyStore instance entries by calling `aliases()` and find each entry in it. It can either be a KeyPair (PublicKey and PrivateKey) or a Certificate or a Data Object (if it is PIV SmartCard token). You can have another instance of JKS KeyStore and you can now do `jksKS.setEntry(...)` or `jksKS.setCertificateEntry(...)`.

If the token doesn't support creation of non-sensitive data, you won't be able to create the PKCS11 Object with the above attributes in the first place.
If the token doesn't support extraction, the PKCS11 token would throw exception saying that sensitive data cannot be extracted.